# "'NoneType' object is not iterable" error when appending a list

Tags: python, list

I would like to add to a list and sort it alphabetically when more is added.
This comes up with the error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
   toPrint = []
   toPrint = toPrint.append("b")
   toPrint = toPrint.append("a")
   toPrint = sorted(toPrint)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current code is assigning `toPrint` to `None` with this line:

```
toPrint = toPrint.append("b")
```

Instead, you should make your code like this:

```
toPrint = []
toPrint.append("b")
toPrint.append("a")
toPrint = sorted(toPrint)
```

Remember that `list.append` is an in-place method.  Meaning, it always returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

`append()` returns `None`, not the list it is applied to, and you cannot pass `None` to `sorted()`.